# Add web-api Controller to an existing asp,net mvc5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My solution had 2 mvc project and 2 web-api project.

** Mvc Projcet 1 - localhost:1230/

** Mvc Project 2 - localhost:1231/center/

** Api Project 1 - localhost:1232/api/

** Api Project 2 - localhost:1232/api/file/

I want to web-api controller to "Mvc Project 2".
So I installed package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi'.
And completed configuring like this.

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
   }
}
```

**Global.aspx**

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        DrDB.Common.AppInfo.AppType = "Web";
        DrDB.Common.AppInfo.EntryAssembly = typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly;

        System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
```

**AcoountServiceController**

```
namespace center.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
    public class AccountServiceController : ApiController{
        [Route("UserInfo")]
        public UserInfoViewModel GetUserInfo()
        {
              ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);

              return "test";
        }
    }
}
```

And then I accessed 'localhost:1231/center/api/Account/UserInfo/', I got 404 Error.

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

So, I try to make helpPage, Installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Helppage'.
And helpPage show not only 'AccountServiceController' but also **Api Project 1**'s Controller.

How can I fixed it?
I want to use 'localhost:1231/center/api/Account/UserInfo/'.

Comment: Did you try moving GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); to top of filters registration?